# Authentication failure during DoctrineMigrationsBundle and DoctrineFixturesBundle upgrade

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Maybe this is a very simple question, but I just can not figure out.

I just upgraded to symfony2.0.17, but during the upgrade process (by php bin/vendors install with deps and deps.lock files provided by symfony website), the DoctrineMigrationsBundle and DoctrineFixturesBundle asked for username and password, I tried my Mac username and password, and also mySQL username and password but all failed.

Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me as well... the solution for me was to delete the contents of the vendors folder and run `php bin/vendors install` again.